# The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules

Tags: netbeans, java-8, java, java-6

Complete error message:
The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules 
Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information.

Some details: I just installed Netbeans on Linux mint for the first time and when I start it when its turning on modules this error message appears. But I do have jdk installed.

$ java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

$ javac -version

```
javac 1.8.0_66
```

Comment: You have the JRE installed, but you (also) need the JDK

Comment: To quickly check if you have a JDK, try `javac -version` - the Java compiler is part of the JDK, not part of the JRE.

Comment: Added that command result to the question

Comment: check the file etc/netbeans.conf under where you installed netbeans and find the line that starts with `netbeans_jdkhome=` Is that pointing to the correct JDK directory?

Comment: It was probably that. I uninstalled and installed the netbeans that comes with JDK and it worked... thanks anyway

Answer (score 83):

Find the file `[netbeans installation directory]/etc/netbeans.conf`

Luckily, Linux has a `find` helper like
`find /home/ -name "netbeans.conf`,
in which you can change the `/home/` to a location where you want to search.

I found it at `/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/etc/netbeans.conf`

Once, you found the file, the following property needs to be set:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="[jdk_path]"
```

where you can find the **jdk_path** using:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

In my case, I found it at `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_191`

Comment: netbeans_jdkhome = should be path of JDK?

Comment: On my system using open-jdk the path is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Comment: On Windows it's in the Netbeans installation directory e.g. C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\etc

Comment: Yes this works.  You can also enter this as [netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"]  where [default-java] is a symbolic link to the actual JDK directory.  This is what I did for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This works, on Ubuntu with netbeans 8.2 the path is ~/netbeans for netbeans.conf and /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ for JDK

Comment: @Quaternion sorry to bother you, I did try with openJDK, but it does not work for some reason. Netbeans 8.2 + latest OpenJDK available from Ubuntu 16.04 apt. Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Did the NB install succeed? If should require the JDK to be set during the install and then it would be rare for things to not work, if the install did not succeed what error are you getting? What is the result of running the command: "update-java-alternatives -l" in the shell? It should list all installed java versions... Review this site: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04 also stability is good for deployment but for development cutting edge I find to be the best (Ubuntu 17.04).

Comment: On Kali Linux 2017.1, netbeans.conf was in (/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/etc) and JDK in (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64)

Answer (score 7):

[Solved] For Mac OSX 10.11 (El Capitan).
Solution may be similar for other Unix-based systems.

The problem may have occurred because I inadvertently installed the jre
prior to installing the jdk.  I uninstalled the jre, installed the jdk
and reinstalled NetBeans but the problem (popup window) remained.
However, the fix was fairly simple.

```
1. Make sure NetBeans is not running.

2. Make sure the jdk is installed.

3. Determine the location of the jdk:
The jdk location can be determined by entering the following (in Terminal):

$ /usr/libexec/java_home

For my system, the output was:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home

4. Edit the NetBeans configuration file to indicate the location of the jdk.
Near the bottom of this Netbeans configuration file (or equivalent for your NetBeans version):
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
Comment out the following line (insert a # before the first character):

#netbeans_jdkhome="/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/bin/jre"

Then, add the following line (or equivalent for your jdk version):

netbeans_jkdhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home"

Then, save and exit the editor.

5. Start NetBeans (no more popup window indicating that the jdk is missing).
```

Comment: It worked using netbeans 8.2 RC, JDK 1.8, and macOS BigSur 11.0.1 Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

When netbeans has problems trying to find the path of the jdk, it's mainly because the version of the jdk does not match.  Open the file C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\etc\netbeans.conf, and verify that netbeans_jdkhome = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111".

Answer (score 2):

1. Open netbeans.conf

`sudo nano "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/netbeans.conf`"

2. Set proper sdk path:

> netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

3. Exit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and to save changes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This error showed up when I updated the Mac to Mojave.  To fix, I edited the netbeans.conf file with the current jdk by using Terminal to find the correct jdk. Type
**/usr/libexec/java_home -V**

Here was my output.

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.8.311.11 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_131 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_25 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_79 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Entering the first jdk listed did not work.
I edited the conf file with the second one listed:
**netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home"**

Restarted Netbeans. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
1. install full JDK
2. either edit <netbeans-IDE-installation>/etc/netbeans.conf
    2.1 unmark netbeans_jdkhome
    2.2 link to JDK location e.g. /usr/local/share/java/jdk1.6.0_07/ 
3. or use --jdkhome command-line option e.g. ./bin/netbeans --jdkhome /usr/local/share/java/jdk1.6.0_07/
```

take care with the "/" at the end

More info in http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

1. Uninstall the netbeans you have.
2. Delete `.cache/netbeans` folder
3. Download http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html
4. Install your download

Comment: i dont think .cache folder related to this, i just experiencing this after deleting .cache folder and reinstall netbeans

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem to. But now i resolove this problem with edit one line.

1. Find and open this file /etc/**netbeans.conf**
2. If you see **netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151"** replace **netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"**
3. Save as adminstrator

Problem reseloved

Answer (score 0):

In mid April 2019, Oracle has changed the JDK's licence. However, I was still able to solve this issue with NetBeans 11 and the JDK 12's open source build on my Windows machine. Just downloaded the open source JDK from https://jdk.java.net/ and extracted it. Then, in my NetBeans config file, I typed in the path to the extracted directory (NOT the "bin" folder!).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by changing default version of JRE and JDK that I'm using to 11.x.x with following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```