# Using the correct JDK or changing default in Netbeans on Linux OS

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

Disclaimer: I am new to Java, new to Linux, and new to Netbeans - apologies for any over/under explanation - please ask and I will add/remove info.

I have a model written in Java in **Netbeans 8.2** that has been successfully running in NetBeans 8.2 on Mac OS. This version of NetBeans was downloaded with **JDK8u171** (JDK/Java package).

All components of the model have successfully transferred through FTP (filezilla) to a remote Linux machine.

The Linux machine has a copy of **Netbeans 8.2** and has **java/1.8.0-oracle** (and 1.6.0 and 1.7.0), and has **java/1.8.0-openjdk** (similarly, 1.6.0 and 1.7.0 also).

I am assuming that 1.8.0-oracle is the equivalent of JDK8u171 but I may well be wrong.

When I load netbeans using

```
module load java/1.8.0-oracle
module load netbeans
netbeans
```

The program opens (via remote desktop - **x2goclient**), and I can search for the project and open it.

Once open, I see:

'*myprojectitle (broken)*' in the project window on the left of the NetBeans GUI

right click -> resolve problems

...opens a screen saying

*'The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information.'*

Does this mean I am using the wrong jdk/java package?

Or is the jdk package configured incorrectly in Netbeans, if so how can I reconfigure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744455/the-jdk-is-missing-and-is-required-to-run-some-netbeans-modules). Please update your post with what you tried if you still have problems after reviewing the answers to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was found at 
[The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744455/the-jdk-is-missing-and-is-required-to-run-some-netbeans-modules)

Whereby, java/1.8.0_171 needed to be installed and then netbeans needed to be opened as follows:

```
netbeans --jdkhome /path/java/1.8.0_171
```

Apologies for a repeat, but hopefully this answer can either redirect or offer a solution